# Mysql - select entries not present in specified tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
mysql> describe messages;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msgID  | varchar(36)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time   | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sender | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hash   | varchar(44)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| msg    | varchar(400) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe user1;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msgID | varchar(36) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe user2;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msgID | varchar(36) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to select all entries from table 'messages' where the msgID is not in tables 'user1' or 'user2'.

I tried this:

```
mysql> select * from messages where msgID not in 
(select msgID from user1) 
union 
(select msgID from user2);
```

But it resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number 
of columns
```

I replaced * with 'msgID', but the result was incorrect.

What should I do?

The number of 'user' tables can be more than 2, by the way, so the solution should be flexible enough for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (only changed the grouping):

```
mysql> select * from messages where msgID not in (
    select msgID from user1
    union 
    select msgID from user2
)
```

Your original query was interpreted as:

```
select * from messages where msgID not in (select msgID from user1) 

union 

(select msgID from user2);
```

And since `messages` has more columns than the single one you're selecting from `users2`, it did not know how to "union"